# Confused by voltage and voltage drop with different kinds of power supplies

Tags: power-supply, arduino, circuit-analysis, voltage

I found a voltage drop behaviour that I don't understand and would like some help please. I have a simple circuit connected to my Arduino:

[image]

I have two circuits like this, where the only difference is the power (+). One circuit is connected to the VCC pin and the other circuit is connected to a regular output pin on the Arduino.

If I disconnect the voltage stepup converter (open circuit,) I measure 3.3V on both open circuits. If I connect the voltage stepup converter and disconnect the garage opener and measure the two open circuits behind the converter I get 9.5V (as I wanted.)

If I close the two circuits (connect the garage opener) I would expect to drop 9.5V at the garage opener, since its the only Load (at least in the circuit behind the converter) but I only measure a voltage drop of 9.5V in the circuit connected to the VCC, but in the other circuit I only measure a drop of 1.2V.

I measured the current in the circuits (between the converter and garage opener.) In the one connected to the VCC I measured 16mA and in the other one I measured only 5.9mA. From my understanding, this means the resistance of the two circuits is different, but since they share the same load I am confused. Where are the missing 8.3V dropping off to in the second circuit?

I'm guessing it has something to do with the garage opener. I thought I understood the electric parts of the system, but it turns out I don't. Feel free to correct me if I made false assumptions; I'm still learning.

Comment: Arduino outputs can't drive that much current. Don't try to power something off them, just use them to switch power to something.

Comment: We don't know the internal circuits of you garage door opener. Do you have the schematics? Or installation manual? Or any other documentation?

Comment: "From my understanding, this means the resistance of the two circuits is different". No, it means the output resistances of the circuits driving those loads are different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arduino outputs can't power anything much more demanding than an LED.

The step-up converter demands more current when the opener (opener remote control?) is connected. and the arduino can't deliver.

If you're prepared to modify your MT3608 module, you can use the arduino output to drive the enable pin of the MT3608 while leaving the supply pins connected to the arduino's supply.

[image]

Find the pin that's connected to the positive supply. The enable pin, pin 4, is the next one clockwise from there.

You'll need to melt the solder on pin 4 of the MT3608 and bend the pin away from the circuit board without snapping it off (a needle or xacto knife may make a good pry bar for this task).  then solder a wire to it.
Once the wire is connected glue it to the circuit board to prevent accidentally ripping pin4 off the MT3608.

Now run that wire to one of the arduino's GPIO pins (and connect ther other power input terminal to the VCC and ground of the arduino.  If you put a high on the output (and thus the enable pin) the MT3608 will start, a low will make it stop.

Comment: Thank you for you answer! I thought maybe the Arduino has enough powering capability but since that's not the case ill try you advise, though im a beginner in soldering as well. But at least there is room to grow!